# Glide enlarges user image after I close and reopen the app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-glide

I'm building an app in kotlin and have a google sign in feature. Now, when a user sign's in, his picture will be automatically updated to the navigation drawer's imageView as shown here:

[image]

The problem is when I close and restart the app, glide degenerates the picture to this:

[image]

Here is the code in which I call glide (those lines commented out are just things which I've tried to do based on previous stack overflow questions based on this issue) :

```
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(imgUrl)
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform().signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis())))
//                    .apply(RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
//                    .apply(RequestOptions().skipMemoryCache(true))
//                    .apply(RequestOptions().signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                    .into(navUserImage)
```

Here is the xml snippet of that image :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" />
```

After much searching, I understand that there may be a cache problem but I cant seem to get the command right for disabling the cache. I am using the latest glide dependency which is `4.8.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by removing `wrap_content` from my xml code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc" />
```